# how can i make query with jpa many to many and list of condition must be all true

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 2 entities User and Prestation with many to many relationship. I want to get all users having specific Prestation like a list of ID Prestation

my query :

```
@Query("SELECT distinct u FROM User u JOIN u.prestation p where p.id In (:prestationsList)")
public List<User> findAllUser(@Param("prestationsList") List<Integer> prestationsList);
```

But this did not give me the correct data, because (In) return user if one element of my prestationList is true

my User :

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "users_prestations",
             joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
             inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "prestation_id")})

    private Set<Prestations> prestation = new HashSet<>();
}
```

my Prestations :

```
 @Entity
 public class Prestations {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "prestation")
    private Set<User> user = new HashSet<>();
}
```

How should I write this query in JPA?

Answer (score 0):

try using this JPQL query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User u left join u.prestation p where p.id In (:prestationsList)")
public List<User> findAllUser(@Param("prestationsList") List<Integer> prestationsList);
```

if this doesn't work try a native query